# Task Schedule in Laravel5.6.4

Tags: scheduled-tasks

Run a Task Scheduling in laravel 5.6.4.

I cannot identify a error,

Stack trace:

```
0 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/projects/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(474): PDOStatement->execute()
1 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(640): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}('update `stock_t...', Array)
2 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(607): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('update `stock_t...', Array, Object(Closure))
3 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(477): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('update `stock_t...', Array, Object(Closure))
4 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(416): Illuminate\Database\Connection->affectingStatement('update `stock_t...', Array)
5 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2147): Illuminate\Database\Connection->update('update `stock_t...', Array)
6 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/app/Http/Controllers/Sale/SaleRepository.php(703): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->update(Array)
7 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/app/Http/Controllers/Sale/SaleController.php(52): App\Http\Controllers\Sale\SaleRepository->sync(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
8 [internal function]: App\controllerpath->sync(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
9 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
10 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
11 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
12 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(60): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array)
13 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(24): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callClass(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', Array, NULL)
14 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', Array, NULL)
15 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/CallbackEvent.php(68): Illuminate\Container\Container->call('App\\Http\\Contro...', Array)
16 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php(59): Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent->run(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand->fire()
18 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
19mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
20/mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
21/mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
22/mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(182): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
23/mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
24/mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(167): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
25/mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(953): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
26/mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(248): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
27/mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
28/mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate
```

/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    29/mnt/hosting/dev/projects/prorject/artisan(35):Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

Comment: there are two tables stocks and accounts.  i have update stocks tables in stock_account_id, sales_account_id and purchase_account_id. foreign key constraints in accounts table id(stocks three column same foreign key). the set foreign key and execute tack schedule(cron job). error affected in(PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails). but i have remove foreign key then run task schedule working good.

Comment: below link set foreign key set in tables, https://i.ibb.co/NFCRY0F/error.png i tired to run not working.

Comment: please put your code in your question to receive the best answers. I highly recommend reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best help with your question.

Comment: my code is here, http://txt.do/1dzdt or https://textuploader.com/1dzdt!